# What is the difference of sending the parameter like this from the pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

i used integer but i am asking for too much big datas. Will memory usage be the same ? Or speed ?

```
void func1(int *a)
{

}

void func2(int &a)
{

}  

int main()
{
  int a;


  func1(&a); // pointer way
  func2(a); // what is it ? is this also pointer way ?
}
```

Comment: I suggest you read a good book, it'll be explained.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the differences between a pointer variable and a reference variable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in)

Comment: Speaking of good [books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: A quick answer to your question: yes, both versions perform a *pass-by-reference*. But please consider reading a book, you'll save a ton of time (and frustration).

Comment: What is the concern for speed or memory size?  Is your application running on a memory restricted (embedded systems) platform?  Is your application expected to make real-time events?  If not any of these, concern yourself with developing a quality application that is robust.